# Item return in the list after deleting it on Swipe

Tags: android, search, filter, android-recyclerview

I'm having an issue that i'm trying to solve for days.
I have a filter method in my RecyclerView that search for certain items by writing something in an edittext. The RecyclerView is opening in an Dialog and the list is populated from the activity from two edittext and after pressing a button they are going to be added in it.

Till here all working fine but i've added a swipe method that should delete items from that recyclerView but it's working in a strange mode, if i open it and i delete some items all work fine and even if i search for an item and delete it all works fine but the **issue comes when i search for an item then i delete it and then i delete another item without searching for it, so when i close the dialog and reopen it the item deleted normally without searching for it returns to the list.**

Here is a video example of what is heppening https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ycub3db39FQ as you can see i'm searching for 5 deleting it then i deleting 6 and 7 but when i reopen it 6 and 7 are still here. obviously if i delete them again thei will be deleted definitly.

Here is my adapter code and my Dialog method from Activity:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void customAlertItems() {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_data);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);

    final EditText edtSearch = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);

    ImageButton delete = dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivDelete);
    ImageButton close = dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivClose);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    final ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(itemModel);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

            if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT || direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {

                model = itemAdapter.getModel();
                itemAdapter.removeItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                edtSearch.getText().clear();


            }

        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);


    edtSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (edtSearch.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                if (model != null)
                    itemModel.remove(model);
            }
            itemAdapter.getFilter().filter(edtSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase());


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });


    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    edtSearch.requestFocus();
    Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Here is recyclerView adapter

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> implements Filterable {


    private ArrayList<ItemModel> variantiConstructors;
    private ArrayList<ItemModel> mFilteredList;
    private ItemModel itemModel;

    ItemAdapter(ArrayList<ItemModel> exampleList) {
        variantiConstructors = exampleList;
        mFilteredList = variantiConstructors;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemAdapter.ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler, parent, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return new ItemAdapter.ExampleViewHolder(v);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ExampleViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
        ItemModel item = variantiConstructors.get(position);

        holder.desc.setText(item.getCodiceArticolo());
        holder.qta.setText(item.getQta());

        itemModel = item;

        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5C5C5C"));

        } else if (position % 2 == 1) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9E9E9E"));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<ItemModel> results = new ArrayList<>();
                if (mFilteredList == null)
                    mFilteredList = new ArrayList<>(variantiConstructors);
                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                    if (mFilteredList != null && mFilteredList.size() > 0) {
                        for (final ItemModel cd : mFilteredList) {
                            if (cd.getCodiceArticolo().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                                results.add(cd);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                    oReturn.count = results.size(); //newly Aded by ZA
                } else {
                    oReturn.values = mFilteredList;
                    oReturn.count = mFilteredList.size(); //newly added by ZA
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(final CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                variantiConstructors = new ArrayList<>((ArrayList<ItemModel>) results.values);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return variantiConstructors.size();
    }

    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView desc;
        public TextView qta;

        ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Desc);
            qta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Qta);





        }
    }

    ItemModel getModel() {
        return itemModel;

    }

    public ArrayList<ItemModel> getList() {
        return variantiConstructors;
    }

    void removeItem(int position) {
        variantiConstructors.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Here is method from button click where i'm adding items :

```
 conferma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(qta.getText().length() > 4 ){
                MediaPlayer mpFound = MediaPlayer.create(InventarioActivity.this,R.raw.errorsound);
                mpFound.start();
                Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                Objects.requireNonNull(v).vibrate(1000);
                new GlideToast.makeToast(InventarioActivity.this, "QUANTITA' NON VALIDA", GlideToast.LENGTHLONG, GlideToast.FAILTOAST).show();
                qta.clearFocus();
            } else
                if (!code.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    if(TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(code.getText())) {
                        if (code.getText().length() >= 1 && code.getText().length() <= 999999) {
                            if (!qta.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                lastQta.setText(qta.getText().toString());
                                lastCode.setText(code.getText().toString());
                                itemModel.add(new ItemModel(code.getText().toString(), qta.getText().toString()));
                            } else {
                                qta.setText("1");
                                lastQta.setText(qta.getText().toString());
                                lastCode.setText(code.getText().toString());
                                itemModel.add(new ItemModel(code.getText().toString(), qta.getText().toString()));
                            }
                        } else if (code.getText().length() == 8) {

                        // check digit

                         } else if (code.getText().length() == 11) {

                        // check digit

                         } else if (code.getText().length() == 13) {

                        // check digit

                        }
                    }


                code.setText("");
                qta.setText("");
                code.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                Objects.requireNonNull(imm).showSoftInput(code, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            }
         }
    });
```

Comment: From where you are adding data in your `itemModel`

Comment: @NileshRathod added the method of the button click where i'm adding the items. There are some controlls that i'm doing on it

Comment: set `notifyDataChange` to your adapter

Comment: @Sniffer where?  removeItem has yet notifyDataChange in it.

Comment: Yes, after removing

Comment: @JohnKarry can you upload that code with sample project on github

Comment: @NileshRathod https://github.com/UAiGorMan/Inventory here you can find the MainClass (InventoryActivity) the adapter and model classes

Comment: @JohnKarry also add layout files and adapter fille

Comment: @NileshRathod updated, added even the recyclerView layout, the alert Dialog layout and the class layout

Comment: @JohnKarry ok let me check that i will update u soon

Comment: @NileshRathod greate, ill wait for your update. thanks

Comment: @NileshRathod any news?

Comment: @JohnKarry Can you please add this inside onSwiped and after itemAdapter.removeItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()):
**itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**
Seems to me that your getting the wrong value in getAdapterPosition() if you don't update it in the adapter

Comment: check the adapter class, notifyDataSetChanged is yet inside removeItem method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Make below changes in your code it will work for you

> InventarioActivity

```
public class InventarioActivity extends AppCompatActivity   {

    ImageButton back;
    ImageButton send;
    ImageButton itemList;
    EditText code;
    EditText qta;
    TextView lastCode;
    TextView lastQta;
    Button conferma;
    ArrayList<ItemModel> itemModel;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
    ItemModel model;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    String siteFTP;
    String usrFTP;
    String pswFTP;
    String path;

    String RemotesiteFTP;
    String RemoteusrFTP;
    String RemotepswFTP;
    String Remotepath;
    String qt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventario);

        back = findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        send = findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
        itemList = findViewById(R.id.itemList);
        code = findViewById(R.id.barcodeTxt);
        qta = findViewById(R.id.qtaTxt);

        lastCode = findViewById(R.id.lastBarCode);
        lastQta = findViewById(R.id.lastQta);

        conferma = findViewById(R.id.btnConferma);

        itemModel = new ArrayList<>();

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE);

        siteFTP = sharedPreferences.getString("siteLocal", "");
        usrFTP = sharedPreferences.getString("userLocal", "");
        pswFTP = sharedPreferences.getString("pswLocal", "");
        path = sharedPreferences.getString("localInventario", "/gpv/myfile.asc");

        RemotesiteFTP = sharedPreferences.getString("siteRemote", "");
        RemoteusrFTP = sharedPreferences.getString("userRemote", "");
        RemotepswFTP = sharedPreferences.getString("pswRemote", "");
        Remotepath = sharedPreferences.getString("remoteInventario", "");

        btnConferma();
        ItemList();
        onCodeChange();
//        sendFtp();
        qtaControll();

    }

    public void qtaControll() {
        qta.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {

                    if (qta.getText().length() > 4) {
                        if (!code.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                            lastQta.setText("1");
                            lastCode.setText(code.getText().toString());
                            itemModel.add(new ItemModel(code.getText().toString(), "1"));
                        }

                        code.setText(qta.getText());
                        qta.setText("");

                    }

                    if (!code.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(code.getText())) {
                            if (code.getText().length() >= 1 && code.getText().length() <= 999999) {
                                lastQta.setText(qt);
                                lastCode.setText(code.getText().toString());
                                itemModel.add(new ItemModel(code.getText().toString(), qt));
                            }
                        } else if (code.getText().length() == 8) {

                            // check digit

                        } else if (code.getText().length() == 11) {

                            // check digit

                        } else if (code.getText().length() == 13) {

                            // check digit

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });


        code.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (!b) {
                    if (qta.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        qt = "1";
                    } else {
                        qt = qta.getText().toString();
                        if (!code.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                            if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(code.getText())) {
                                if (code.getText().length() >= 1 && code.getText().length() <= 999999) {
                                    lastQta.setText(qt);
                                    lastCode.setText(code.getText().toString());
                                    itemModel.add(new ItemModel(code.getText().toString(), qt));
                                }
                            } else if (code.getText().length() == 8) {

                                // check digit

                            } else if (code.getText().length() == 11) {

                                // check digit

                            } else if (code.getText().length() == 13) {

                                // check digit

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }


    public void onCodeChange() {
        code.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    qta.requestFocus();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    public void ItemList() {
        itemList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                customAlertItems();
            }
        });
    }


    public void btnConferma() {
        conferma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (qta.getText().length() > 4) {
//                    MediaPlayer mpFound = MediaPlayer.create(InventarioActivity.this,R.raw.errorsound);
//                    mpFound.start();
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    Objects.requireNonNull(v).vibrate(1000);
                    Toast.makeText(InventarioActivity.this, "QUANTITA' NON VALIDA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    qta.clearFocus();
                } else if (!code.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(code.getText())) {
                        if (code.getText().length() >= 1 && code.getText().length() <= 999999) {
                            if (!qta.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                lastQta.setText(qta.getText().toString());
                                lastCode.setText(code.getText().toString());
                                itemModel.add(new ItemModel(code.getText().toString(), qta.getText().toString()));
                            } else {
                                qta.setText("1");
                                lastQta.setText(qta.getText().toString());
                                lastCode.setText(code.getText().toString());
                                itemModel.add(new ItemModel(code.getText().toString(), qta.getText().toString()));
                            }
                        } else if (code.getText().length() == 8) {

                            // check digit

                        } else if (code.getText().length() == 11) {

                            // check digit

                        } else if (code.getText().length() == 13) {

                            // check digit

                        }
                    }


                    code.setText("");
                    qta.setText("");
                    code.requestFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    Objects.requireNonNull(imm).showSoftInput(code, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void customAlertItems() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_data);

        recyclerView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);

        final EditText edtSearch = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);

        ImageButton delete = dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivDelete);
        ImageButton close = dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivClose);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, itemModel);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

                if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT || direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
                    model = itemAdapter.getModel(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                    Log.e("DATA_VALUE",model.getCodiceArticolo());
                    itemModel.remove(model);
                    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    edtSearch.getText().clear();
                }

            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);


        edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                itemAdapter.getFilter().filter(edtSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtSearch.getText().toString())) {
                    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(InventarioActivity.this, itemModel);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
                }

            }
        });


        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (itemAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
                    itemModel.clear();
                } else {
//                    itemModel = itemAdapter.getList();
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        edtSearch.requestFocus();
        Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.show();
    }


}
```

> ItemAdapter

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> implements Filterable {


    private ArrayList<ItemModel> variantiConstructors;
    private ArrayList<ItemModel> mFilteredList;
    private ItemModel itemModel;
    private Context mContext;

    ItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemModel> exampleList) {
        variantiConstructors = exampleList;
        mFilteredList = variantiConstructors;
        mContext = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemAdapter.ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler, parent, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return new ItemAdapter.ExampleViewHolder(v);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ExampleViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
        ItemModel item = variantiConstructors.get(position);

        holder.desc.setText(item.getCodiceArticolo());
        holder.qta.setText(item.getQta());


        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5C5C5C"));

        } else if (position % 2 == 1) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9E9E9E"));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<ItemModel> results = new ArrayList<>();
                if (mFilteredList == null)
                    mFilteredList = new ArrayList<>(variantiConstructors);
                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                    if (mFilteredList != null && mFilteredList.size() > 0) {
                        for (final ItemModel cd : mFilteredList) {
                            if (cd.getCodiceArticolo().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                                results.add(cd);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                    oReturn.count = results.size(); //newly Aded by ZA
                } else {
                    oReturn.values = mFilteredList;
                    oReturn.count = mFilteredList.size(); //newly added by ZA
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(final CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                variantiConstructors = new ArrayList<>((ArrayList<ItemModel>) results.values);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return variantiConstructors.size();
    }

    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView desc;
        public TextView qta;

        ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Desc);
            qta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Qta);


        }
    }

    ItemModel getModel(int pos) {
        return variantiConstructors.get(pos);

    }

    public ArrayList<ItemModel> getList() {
        return variantiConstructors;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please host your project from the video on github, because believe or not but still having same problem

Comment: @JohnKarry ok sure

Comment: i just can't get even with your app i'm having same issue https://gyazo.com/aaa91fa8e606d6d081fb432501d7ffa4 check this gif

Comment: @JohnKarry have u download the project because it s working fine for me

Comment: yes i've downloaded the project, try to do that i'm doing, like put 1,2,3,4,5 search for 1 then delete 4 then close the dialog and open it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181234/discussion-between-johnkarry-and-nilesh-rathod).

Comment: hm almost working just there is another problem ill send you a gif in a while

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FmYGNKS5pg&feature=youtu.be so as you can see the old issue is fixed but if i search then delete then delete and search again and just delete the number from edittext the items are not that they had to be

Comment: Like i've searched for 2 in the video deleted it then i deleted 4 then searched for 6 but didn't deleted it and just cleared the edittext and in the recyclerView instead of 3/6 it's showing 3/4 when i deleted 4

Comment: @JohnKarry finally i'm able solve your issue Please check my updated answer

Comment: @JohnKarry welcome Glad to have been of help keep in touch